# Is it good to go ahead with webservice load testing?

Tags: web-services, jmeter

We have an application which is meant for Android, iOS and desktop all 3 and all 3 are consuming webservices.

What I would like to know is that, should we record scenarios from Android, iOS and desktop seperately and make script or we can just hit the web services using jmeter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well-behaved load test should represent application under test real-life usage as close as possible. If desktop, Android and iOS applications use the same endpoint and send the same requests in terms of parameters - it will be enough to come up with only one [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) holding request(s) representing the load.

If there are differences depending on the platform i.e. in request parameters, [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers), [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies), etc.  - it's better to go for different Thread Groups representing different users sitting on different platforms or consider using i.e. [Throughput Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability) to mimic real anticipated distribution of the requests basing on the source platform.